# Notifications on envelope's status

Tags: docusignapi

In the eventNotification/envelopeEvents section of the Create Envelope request it should be sent a list of all the statuses that we want to be notified of? The statuses not included there won't be notified to the callback endpoint?

Sending this (sample of the eventNotification/envelopeEvents section of the jSON) would prevent DocuSign to send updates on voided documents?

```
"eventNotification": {
    "url": "https://fakeurl.com",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "true",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [{
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed",
            "includeDocuments": "true"
        },
        {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined",
            "includeDocuments": "true"
        },
        {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered",
            "includeDocuments": "false"
        },
        {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent",
            "includeDocuments": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.
Note, that this means of using Connect "per envelope" has some limitations.
The other option is to set up a Connect Configuration, which is account-wide, for all envelopes, and has more functionality.
More information on The [Developer Center DocuSign Connect Documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/).